# Field problem in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I dragged a field into the details section, but it shows only one row and repeats everything that is there in the details section and then it shows the next row. I want that CourseID2 should come just below CourseID1 and nothing else should be repeated.

Comment: When I run the report it should show two rows. First shows CourseID1 and CourseName1 and just below CourseID1 it should display CourseID2 and its CourseName2 below CourseName1.

Comment: :-D That's not what I meant! Anyway, in the bottom right on the preview, it shows how many records are present. How many does it show?

Comment: If you preview the report, the Crystal screen will show how many records are returned from the table or query.  Look on the bottom, right-hand side of the screen and it will say "Records: 10" or another number.  That's the first thing I do when I have this problem.

Comment: It returns 2 records from the database

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your tables joined is causing your "extra" records. If you're not understanding your join and you're looking for a quick-fix/hack to your problem, you can simply add a group on your CourseID field and move your "detail" fields into the new Group Header section. After that, Suppress your Detail section and Group Footer section. This will leave just your Group Header section showing on the report, and it's impossible to get duplicate records from your Group Header section.

You need to develop a better understanding of your data though, and how your joins affect the outcome of your query.